# Network adapter is missing in Device Manager

Tags: internet, internet-connection

I can't connect to Wi-Fi because the Intel network adapter is missing in the network adapter so I searched many methods to fix it, but it made it worse because now I can't find the whole network adapter option in Device Manager. The troubleshooter said that I need to reinstall the driver, so I manually download Intel network adapter and run it, I think that is the reason behind the disappearance.

How can I fix it? I tried System Restore but there is only one option and after I restored, it is still missing and I can't still connect to internet.

Here how my Mevice manager looks:

[image: Screenshot of Device Manager]

Comment: now I can't find the whole network adapter option in device manager.  ....  That indicates a possible hardware issue with the network adapter. Try a USB Wireless network adapter to see if that works.

Comment: If it's missing then it's broken.